# Python: Port scann on localhost

Tags: python, sockets, port

I've greatet a port scanner in python, that can check the open ports of an public and local IP.
A Portscann on an public IP works fine, but when i try a scann on localhost (127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0) it say on every port that this is closed...

Heres the Code:

```
    try:
    for port in range(int(sport), int(eport) + 1):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServer, port))
        if result == 0:
            print("[+] Port " + str(port) + " = [Open]")
        else:
            print("[-] Port " + str(port) + " = [Closed]")
        sock.close()
except:
    print("\nScan failed!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Check your IP adress.\n")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("The programm will be closed...")
    time.sleep(4)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: First i scanned "scanme.nmap.org" from Port 20 to 25 (external). Result = 20,21,23,24 and 25 was closed and port 22 opend....so far so good. But when i try to scann 127.0.0.1 (local) then it says port 20 to 25 are closed...

Comment: You have any service running on these ports?

Comment: Yea....I also tried 54, 80 etc. but nothing works and its not blocked by the firewall....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Maybe your server just binds the public ip (maybe in its config file, there is a config about the ip it binds), so this server can be visited by others.
2. If the server bind 127.0.0.1(Loop back address), maybe others can not visit it except yourself.

So I think the first situation(bind public ip), it doesn't bind 127.0.0.1(Loop back address), leading to your failure to scan them. Or in another word, the public ip and Loop back address represent 2 different network devices.

Comment: Yea but I createt only one socket and its running local on the device...

Comment: 1. In your socket server config, try to bind 0.0.0.0 (not your actually public ip and Loop back address), it maybe useful for your situation. 2. Or use a different way, you can get your public ip in your scanner.py to avoid scanning Loop back address.